# How to exit exe process on c#?

Tags: c#, process

How to  exit process on this scenario on Application Exit or on Exit Button.

```
namespace test2
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe");
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.Arguments = "-i " + urltext.Text.Trim() + "?fifo_size=1000000 -map 0:p:" + Channeltext.Text.Trim() + " -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time " + splittimetext.Text.Trim() + " " + filenametext.Text.Trim() + "-%03d.ts";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
}
```

How to exit process on this scenario on Application Exit.

Comment: Sorry. What? What does "How to exit process on this scenario on Application Exit" mean. Do you mean *your application*? The application you're launching using `Process.Start()`? Something else? Are you asking how to exit your application, or to close the one you're starting? It's unclear what you're asking; you are going to need to [edit] to make it more understandable what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ken White: sorry i didn't mention that i need to kill the exe process which i call.

Answer (score 5):

Save the process instance to variable , then subscribe to [ProcessExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), when the event is triggered, kill the process.

```
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (a,b) => process.Kill();
```

Comment: I agree on this. It's better than allocating process name as I and others have entailed. +1

Comment: @AmitApollo I don't see anything better from what I proposed apart from this being more concise, which could be done in my case too with `this.FormClosing += (s, e) => myProcess.Kill();`

Comment: I've tried your solution. It works fine if the application is closed by User, but didn't work when closed by **Visual Studio** (in mode Debug). Could we manage both of them properly?

Answer (score 2):

Keep a reference to your process as a class member.

```
Process myProcess;
```

In the method where you start the process

```
myProcess = new Process(startInfo);
myProcess.Start();
```

And finally, subscribe to an event that occurs when the form finishes/finished and kill the process by calling `myProcess.Kill();`

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    try { myProcess.Kill(); }
    catch { ... }
}
```

Comment: This method is not works.... Actually need to close the FFMPEG.exe process which i call on close the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially kill the process eventually using the code below:

```
try {
    foreach(System.Diagnostics.Process myProc in System.Diagnostics.
        Process.GetProcesses())
          if (myProc.ProcessName == "process name")
            myProc.Kill();
   } catch(Exception ex) {}
```

put this under OnExit() method and override.

Comment: This method is not works.... Actually need to close the FFMPEG.exe process which i call on close the application.

Comment: Go to task manager and figure out the Process name. It may not be FFMPEG.exe, it should tell you in it.

Comment: On the Task Manager it shows FFMPEG.exe *32. Should i write this on process name?

Answer (score 0):

Child processes should close automatically, but if its holding you main app up from closing then store them in a public list for later closure.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form        
{
    List<Process> myProcesses = new List<Process>();
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess in myProcesses)
        {
            myProcess.Close();
        }
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = "-i " + urltext.Text.Trim() + "?fifo_size=1000000 -map 0:p:" + Channeltext.Text.Trim() + " -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time " + splittimetext.Text.Trim() + " " + filenametext.Text.Trim() + "-%03d.ts";
        myProcesses.add(System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo));
    }
}
```

This example uses a list incase you plan to have multiple ones.

Comment: Your idea is exactly what i want.. but your method won't works... kindly guide.

Comment: What do you mean won't work? you simply need to store the reference to the started process created as a return from the .start() method then refer to this stored process and call .close(), it can be stored as a Process or a list<Process> or dictionary<int,Process> or pretty much however best suits you.